# Tkinter Canvas, Deletion of Images

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am very frustrated at this, as it is completely stupid as to why it isn't working.

I have:

```
import random as rand
import time
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height = 800, width = 1300)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
root.title('Test')
root.update_idletasks()
root.update()

bench1Xadd = 0
bench1Yadd = 0
vCard1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'card1.gif')

b1Card1 = canvas.create_image(50, 500, anchor = 'nw', image = vCard1)
root.update()
time.sleep(0.03)
canvas.delete("all")
root.update()

input('')

def imageAdd(vCard, slot, x, y):
    slot = canvas.create_image(x, y, anchor = 'nw', image = vCard)
    return slot

imageAdd(vCard1, b1Card1, 50 + bench1Xadd, 500 - bench1Yadd)
root.update()


input('')
canvas.delete(b1Card1)
root.update()
```

Why isn't the `canvas.delete()` working?

If I forgot anything specific, I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b1Card1` represents the first image you create, which you almost immediately delete. Later, when you try to delete it again, it doesn't exist so nothing will be deleted.

Passing `b1Card1` to `imageAdd` does *not* cause it to be updated with the new value. Instead, you need to save the result of `imageAdd`:

```
b1Card1 = imageAdd(...)
```